# Extracting data from .txt file

Tags: python, twitter

For my programming assignment, one of the functions involves taking input from a text file (twitter data) and returning a tuple of the tweet information (see doctests for correct results on a sample file).

Sample text file: http://pastebin.com/z5ZkN3WH

Full description of function is as follows:

> The parameter is the full name of a file. Open the file specified by the parameter, which is formatted as described in the data files section, and read all of the data from it. The keys of the dictionary should be the names of the candidates, and the items in the list associated with each candidate are the tweets they have sent. A tweet tuple should have the form (candidate, tweet text, date, source, favorite count, retweet count). The date, favorite count, and retweet count should be integers, and the rest of the items in the tuple should be strings.

My code so far is below:

```
def extract_data(metadata):
    """ list of str -> tuple of str/int

    Return extracted metadata in specified format.
    """
    date = int(metadata[1])
    source = metadata[3]
    favs = int(metadata[4])
    retweets = int(metadata[5])

    return date, source, favs, retweets

def read_tweets(file):
    """ (filename) -> dict of {str: list of tweet tuples}

    Read tweets from file and categorize into dictionary.

    >>> read_tweets('very_short_data.txt')
    {'Donald Trump': [('Donald Trump', 'Join me live in Springfield, Ohio!\\nhttps://t (dot) co/LREA7WRmOx\\n', 1477604720, 'Twitter for iPhone', 5251, 1895)]}
    """

    result = {}
    with open(file) as data:
        tweets = data.read().split('<<<EOT')
        for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
            line = tweet.splitlines()
            content = ' '.join(line[2:])
            meta = line[1].split(',')
            if ':' in line[0]:
                author = line[0]
                metadata = extract_data(meta)
            else:
                metadata = extract_data(meta)

            candidate = author

            result[candidate] = [(candidate, content, metadata)]

        return result
```

This currently results in an error: "date = int(metadata[1]) IndexError: list index out of range". I am not sure why, or what to do next. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Since this is for educational work (CS, UofT), I would hate to just give you the answer.  Instead, working backwards ... what does "IndexError: list index out of range" tell you about your list `metadata[1]`?  What does it tell you about the `1` index?  You can see by printing out `metadata` just before the line that fails.

Comment: ['791697302519947264', '1477604720', 'Ohio USA', 'Twitter for iPhone', '5251', '1895']
['781619038699094016', '1475201875', 'United States', 'Twitter for iPhone', '31968', '17246']
['Secretary Hillary Clinton:']

Comment: It seems to be working successfully until the last tweet in the test file.

Comment: Since you are splitting tweets on "<<<EOT", I think maybe the last tweet would be the empty string.  I see in the pastebin "<<<EOT" at the bottom of the file followed by empty string.  And so `split(',')` on empty string returns list of size 1.  And so `metadata[1]` fails since that's access the non-existent 2nd element of the list.

Comment: The third tweet (last actual tweet in the file) is the one by Clinton. When running in pythontutor.com, I see that for some reason, the content is picked up as "791720798226640896,1477610322,Unknown Location,TweetDeck,545,226 \"Folks marched &amp; protested for our right to vote. They endured beatings and jail time. They sacrificed their lives for this right.\" --@FLOTUS", which is the metadata **and** tweet content. But when it comes time to grab the metadata, nothing happens.

Comment: Not really.  Print out `len(tweets)`.  Is it 3 or 4?  To you, the last tweet is is the one by Clinton.  But to the computer (confuser?), `.split('<<<EOT')` will include whatever is after the last "<<<EOT", which is an empty string which will be the (unexpected) 4th tweet you process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea spliting by EOT considering candidates with empty tweets don't have EOT. it is better to loop through the contents instead of reading all the data at once. it makes it a lot easier.

doing same assignment stuck on this func aswell :(